# This smooth scroll function is not working, despite of setting the correct target

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code for the smooth scroll and I have correctly imported it from React library still it yeilds no result:

```
const scrollToNextSection = () => { 
  scroller.scrollTo("SecondSection", { smooth: true, duration: 1500 });
};
```

here is the image of the section being called

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have did with native DOM method [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

It may not be an efficient example but the scroll is smooth as expected

For better view see this [code sandbox link - smooth scroll](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-robinson-p9eur?file=/src/styles.css:0-199)

- used Ref's

```js
const App = () => {
  const refOrange = React.useRef(null);
  const refBlue = React.useRef(null);

  function scrollToNode(node) {
    node.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        ref={refBlue}
        onClick={() => scrollToNode(refOrange)}
        className="div1"
      >
        Click to smooth scroll to orange
      </div>
      <div
        ref={refOrange}
        onClick={() => scrollToNode(refBlue)}
        className="div2"
      >
        Click to smooth scroll to sky blue
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.div2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 72, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="root"></div>
```